# How do I troubleshoot WiFi networking issues with my iOS 12.2 iPhone 8? Can't load apple.com

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

How do I troubleshoot networking issues with my iPhone 8 plus with iOS 12.2? I can't even load web pages like apple.com or status.twitter.com. The progress bar is stuck at 10%. It seemed to work OK with the previous iOS, but I only had it for a while.

- Problem occurs with Podcast, YouTube, Safari.
- I don't have any issues with my desktop connected via Ethernet cable.
- I turned the phone off and on. It helps for a while.
- An app called Ping Lite shows pings to 10.0.0.1, my router/cable modem, has 0% packet loss and about 10ms. Pings to google.com shows 0% packet loss and about 30ms average. Pings to apple.com times out 100%.
- An app called Speedtest shows 12-17.8Mbs down and 2.4Mbs up, with ping 14ms.
- I kill the app and start it again, but that doesn't seem to help.
- When I turn on airplane mode and off again, then it works for a bit. After a while, the WiFi stops. YouTube will say "Not connected to the internet. Tap to retry."
- Doesn't seem to help to rest my phone on the router.
- My old iPhone 5/iOS 10.3.3 never had these problems.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Start off by turning off WiFi and only use your mobile data.  Does everything work?

Comment: Yes mobile cellular data works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are chances where your Wifi router doesn't support the Apple or in the wifi network there can be chances where you need to do make some changes.

But before that try to go to Settings -> General -> Reset and choose Reset Network Settings.

You’ll have to reconnect to all your Wi-Fi networks and enter their passwords again, so make sure you know the important ones before you begin. Try reconnecting to your wireless router after your iPhone reboots. If it still won’t connect, it’s time to take a [look at your wireless router](https://www.payetteforward.com/my-iphone-wont-connect-to-wi-fi-heres-the-fix/2/).

Comment: Resetting the network settings worked for about 10 minutes, but now it is back to being flakey for any content over a few hundred bytes. I don’t see how it can by my router if my iPad 9.3.5 works for streaming.

Comment: Did you check your phone working on other WIFI routes? And does it works on that ?